# What is the size of byte code stored in the EVM?

Tags: evm, bytecode

Generally, what is the size of the bytecode stored in the EVM. I mean the approx average value of it or bytecode of a simple hello world program (setting and getting a  string). 
On what factors this bytecode depends? and on how can i get this correct. i mean How can I know the correct value? is there any predefined keyword or command that gives this information.

Any relatable answer is appreciable !!

Answer (score 2):

> I mean the approx average value of it or bytecode of a simple hello world program (setting and getting a string).

I'm not aware of anyone tracking these statistic, you will have to compute them yourself. Contract can vary a huge amount in size.

> On what factors this bytecode depends?

It is more or less directly proportional to the length of your source code, although optimization runs can make the compiled size deviate from a purely linear relationship.

> and on how can i get this correct. i mean How can I know the correct value? is there any predefined keyword or command that gives this information.

The `eth_getCode` function allows you retrieve the bytecode at a given address.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at Ethereum's mainnet, as of late September (last time I processed contracts and addresses for stats):

- There are approximately 125,000 unique contracts, many more if you count duplicates
- Most contracts range from a few hundreds of bytes (generally a few Kb) up to almost 25 Kb for the largest active contract

I can't say for testnets, private nets (of course!) or other Ethereum forks.